# Pycharm's code style inspection: ignore/switch off specific rules

Tags: python, pycharm, pep8

I'm trying to import existing project into PyCharm. I can refactor the code so that PyCharm will be pleased, but we like to have spaces around colons in dictionaries, like this: `{"A" : "B"}`. We also like aligning assignments:

```py
a   = 1
abc = 3
```

Is there a way to configure PyCharm, so that he'll ignore all errors/warnings related to this specific stuff?

Answer (score 65):

Using **PyCharm 5 (community edition)**, you can do the following: `Code –> Inspect Code`.  Then select the required inspection error, and click on the "**Suppress**" option or "**Ignore errors like this**" option on right hand side.
Please look at the screenshot below:

[image]

When you choose the "**Suppress**" option, it adds a comment as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Suppressing can be done at the statement, or function/method, levels. If trying to suppress an argument to a function, the suppression only works at the function level (meaning it also suppresses other name reference violations that might exist within that function).

You also have the option of switching off "**PEP8 coding style violations**" altogether (by ticking the box shown below), or explicitly managing "**Ignore Errors**" manually. Screenshot given below:

[image]

In general, you should perhaps question why you are suppressing PEP8 guidelines. However, sometimes it appears necessary, for instance when using the `pytest` module, it is necessary to shadow variables, etc, which the PEP8 Inspection complains about in. In such cases, this feature in PyCharm is very helpful.

Comment: Note that Suppress modifies the source code (so that no other developers on your project see the warning) while Ignore turns them off just for your machine (local Inspections Profile); other developers with different profiles will still see the warning.

Comment: If you want to deactivate certain errors explicitly like in the last screenshot. Here is a list of PEP8 error codes: http://pep8.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.7.x/intro.html#error-codes

Comment: What do you actually put in the Ignore Errors list?  I can't find an example.

Comment: @ThatAintWorking Check out the link that I posted. There is a list with error IDs. Just add the ones you don't like to the box. E.g. `E701`

Answer (score 6):

If you're ok to ignore all matching issues, you can just press Alt-Enter (or click on the lightbulb) and choose "Disable Inspection". Saves you going into the settings and trying to figure out the inspection rule that matches.

From http://iambigblind.blogspot.jp/2013/02/configuring-pep8py-support-in-pycharm-27.html

Answer (score 5):

@Krzysztof Stanisławek, function is different as Pycharm follows the PEP8 coding style, so it is recommended that there is no whitespace between the function variables and ":", if you don't want this, you can disable it by

```
"Settings"-> "Editor"-> "Inspections"->"PEP8 coding style violation"
```

However, this is not recommended.

Comment: More of a problem is auto-formatter. I can either reformat my code to `{a: b, c: d}` instead of preferred `{a : b, c : d}`, or to `def foo(self) :`. The problem is that formatter treats `:` the same in both cases, there are no separate options for these cases.

I don't think there is a way (it looks like Pycharm is lacking feature I need), so I think I'll either persuade my teammates to change our dicts style to `{a: b}`, or use simple regex to format `:` at the ends of the methods parentheses.

Comment: Found this about disabling specific PEP8 guidelines: http://iambigblind.blogspot.de/2013/02/configuring-pep8py-support-in-pycharm-27.html

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue, and the neat solution has been pointed by @fantabolous, from [configuring PEP8.py support in PyCharm 2.7](http://iambigblind.blogspot.com/2013/02/configuring-pep8py-support-in-pycharm-27.html)

**Example before** 
[image: Code with multiple space warning]

**Adding the error code either manually or with "Alt+Enter" on error highlight** 
The error code can be found [here](https://pep8.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#configuration) 
[image]

**After the changes** 
[image]

It's great to select precisely some rules instead of disabling all warning from PEP8. Thanks to the previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

to have spaces around colons in dictionaries, configure `Settings > Editor > Python` `Spaces`

`Other > Before ':'`

and

`Other > After ':'`

Comment: I forgot to mention: option "before ":"" affects also function definitions, e.g. `def foo() :`.