# Lambda works, defined function does not

Tags: python, lambda, pycharm, pep8

This is working:

```
represent_dict_order = lambda self, data: self.represent_mapping('tag:yaml.org,2002:map', data.items())
yaml.add_representer(OrderedDict, represent_dict_order)
```

But gives me a `PyCharm` warning: `PEP8: do not assign a lambda expression, use a def`

I follow the advice, but this is not working:

```
def represent_dict_order(self, data):
    self.represent_mapping('tag:yaml.org,2002:map', data.items())
yaml.add_representer(OrderedDict, represent_dict_order)
```

I get:

```
yaml.emitter.EmitterError: expected NodeEvent, but got DocumentEndEvent()
```

I have two questions:

1. Why is the `lambda` working and the `def` not? Aren't they supposed to be equivalent?
2. How can I stop `PyCharm` complaining about this specific error? I tried preceeding the lambda with `#noinspection` but it is not recognized.

Comment: Your lambda has a return value compared to your function definition with def.

Comment: @strippenzieher: ooops, implicit return, right. Embarrassing, but I'll accept an answer.

Comment: For your second question, if you mean the PEP8 warning, you would need to ignore E731.See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428307/pycharms-code-style-inspection-ignore-switch-off-specific-rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambda expressions come with an [implicit return](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda). Therefore your lambda expression is returning the return value of `self.represent_mapping` but your function definition is not due to the missing return.

Comment: "Explicit is better than implicit" :)